# android studio SharedPreferences doesn't work

Tags: java, android

i am trying to use `SharedPreferences` to login or register

```
SharedPreferences    sp=getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor Ed=sp.edit();
Log.d("my id",jsonObject.getString("id"));
Ed.putString("userid",jsonObject.getString("id"));
Ed.commit();//or Ed.apply();
```

and in the other code while trying to get it

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences= getSharedPreferences("login", MODE_PRIVATE);
String id= sharedpreferences.getString("userid",null);
if(id==null)//sharedpreferences.contains("userid")==false)
{
    Log.d("pref","No Id");
}
```

and it's always printing `No Id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [**`SharedPreferences`**](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) object points to a file containing **`key-value pairs`** and provides simple methods to read and write them. Each SharedPreferences file is managed by the framework and can be private or shared.

Your **`KEY`** must be same. Read official guideline about [**`getSharedPreferences`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)).

```
 SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set the same key while set and get data. You've set **Login** while set data  and using **login** while get data. Both keys should be same.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting it in `Login` and getting it from `login`. They should be the same.